# XP Blocking all incoming connections - Cannot detect where the problem is

Tags: windows-firewall

I have the following problem. I have installed KERIO Winroute in a machine. 
After trying it I uninstalled from the PC. The problem now is that
I can´t access that machine from network. It seems like something is blocking 
all the ports. (I have disabled Antivirus and Windows firewall).
Does anyone know a tool to diagnosticate the problem or anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks,

Ezequiel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try checking Security Policy (Start -> Run -> secpol.msc).  Sometimes security software will try to enforce local security policies to tighten things up.  We have some software that uses IPSec and consistently sets a security policy that mucks up traffic to/from the machine.  Look in there for anything out of the ordinary or specifically labeled Kerio or Winroute.

I have no experience with this software specifically, just throwing some ideas out there.

Comment: This was exactly my problem with an XP machine a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the TCP stack (using the microsoft tool netsh) and that worked for me.